# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''

Tags: http, authentication, iis

When I try to access an HTTP REST API hosted on a site within my machine’s local IIS, I get this error message:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''."

Anonymous Authentication is enabled in the site’s IIS authentication settings, and the identity of the anonymous user is set to be that of the IUSR role. The IUSR role has read permissions on the underlying virtual directory associated with my IIS site, and I have also tried giving “Everyone” Full Control over the underlying connection virtual directory (see below). Both the virtual directory and the IIS site should have sufficient authentication allowed for anonymous access.
[Project Properties - Security - Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0o1m.png)

The exact same code used in this web project runs perfectly fine on a different computer, so I don’t believe the issue lies in the code.

Stack Trace (snippet):

```
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(PIM.App.Infrastructure.Setttings.ISettingsProvider)' on type 'ServiceFactory'. ---> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''. (See inner exception for details.)","ExceptionType":"Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException","StackTrace":"
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.","ExceptionType":"System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException","StackTrace":"\r\nServer stack trace: \r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)\r\n
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)\r\n
```